# Why is a critical point defined as a stationary inflection point?

Tags: thermodynamics, critical-phenomena

In the analysis of a van der Waals equation of state, it's quite clear that the temperature and pressure at which
$$
\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial V} \right)_T = 0\\
\left( \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial V^2} \right)_T = 0
$$
is obeyed corresponds to the critical point. But that analysis seems to depend intimately on the nature of the particular vdW equation of state. Nevertheless, Wikipedia seems to suggest that these conditions define a critical point quite generally, whether or not a system obeys a vdW equation of state -- why is this? Perhaps my confusion lies in having note seen a rigorous definition of critical point. Callen simply defines it in the context of a vdW equation of state as that temperature and pressure which defines the top of the $pV$ phase envelope.

Comment: In Callen's first edition, he explicitly says that he's not restricting attention to the vdW equation of state: "In order to investigate the detailed consequences of instability, we assume that we have been given a tentative equation of state of the general form indicating schematically in Figure 9.1 *[which appears to be Fig. 9.8 in the second edition – ed.]*. The van der Waals equation has this general form, but we shall not restrict the discussion to any particular analytical equation."

Comment: In the second edition, he writes "Other empirical or semiempirical equations of state exist, and they all have isotherms that are similar to those shown in Fig. 9.8.", but that hardly seemed convincing seeing as it seemed to depend intimately on the given system obeying such an equation of state. At no point did he justify that all (normal) systems *do* in fact obey such an equation of state though?

Comment: Do answers to this previous question ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/657427/understanding-the-critical-temperature-on-a-pv-diagram?rq=1 ) address your question too?

Answer (score 1):

The region of instability for any *simple* matter under hydrostatic pressure is where $\frac{\partial p}{\partial V} >0$, that is where isothermal pressure increases as volume increases. This happens between neighboring minimum and maximum points of $p$ as $V$ increases. If those points coalesce into one then there cannot be a region instability, and this is what happens at $\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial V^2} =0$ where the second derivative is also zero.